# git branching: difference between ``git merge master`` and ``git pull origin master``

Tags: git, version-control, merge

Let's assume that I have a new `feature` branch and a `master` branch. I've made some changes and commited them to the `feature` branch, but then I checkout `master` and add another changes. What I want to do is get the `master`'s changes and apply them to `feature`. What should I do? Merge with `master`?

```
git checkout feature
git merge master
```

Or pull changes from `master`?

```
git checkout feature
git pull origin master
```

What's the difference between those two options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git pull` is essentially a combination of `git fetch` and `git merge`. So the difference to just using `git merge` is that it will first fetch new revisions from the remote repository and *then* perform the merge.

If your local `master` branch is up to date, this will make no difference, but if it is outdated, `git pull` will make sure that you merge the newest changes from the remote repository.

Comment: What really happened in my repo was that I've lost the changes made in ``master`` (not in ``master`` branch itself, but in the resulted ``feature``) when merging with ``feature`` using the first option. It was like the merge operation decided to keep the ``feature`` version of some unmodified files instead of getting the ``master`` version.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all the content that is there in master branch into to the feature branch then you can do

```
git checkout feature
git merge master
```

If you just want to get the commits that you made in master branch and then apply them to the feature branch then you can do the following.

Get the commit id of interest

```
git log master
```

Then switch to the feature branch

```
git checkout feature
```

Then pick the changes from this commit id and apply this to the feature branch. This is called `cherry-pick`'ing in the `git` world

```
git cherry-pick <commid_id>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I did, the first two steps, but the changes were not merged into ``feature``...

Comment: There is a high chance that you may not have committed your changes in to the master branch. I use the above commands day in and out and it works fine.